# Going from the general concept of Frechet differentiabilty to specific comcept of derivative for curves

Tags: real-analysis

I want to go from general to specific, meaning, if I have the definition of  [Frechet differentiability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_derivative#Definition) for real or complex Banach spaces I want to obtain all the other definitions of differentiability for functions between $\mathbb{R}^m$ and $\mathbb{R}^n$ from that.

Now my question is: How can I get from the Frechet derivative, in the case that $V$ is one-dimensional (so isomorphic to $\mathbb{K}=\mathbb{R,C}$), to the following definition of differentiablity (which, as far as I know, is the definition for differentiablity for curves):

$f:\mathbb{K} \rightarrow W$ is differentiable at $x\in U\subseteq \mathbb{K},\ U$ open if  the limit of the function $F:\mathbb{K}\setminus \{0\} \ni h\mapsto  \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}\in W $ in $0$ exists.
The problem I face is that I don't know how to get rid of the norm in the numerator.

This question was motivated by [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/81184/ways-to-calculate-the-derivative-of-the-matrix-exponential) question, where I couldn't really understand the answer, because it assumed an answer to this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this follows from the simple fact that, by definition of the limit, $\lim_{h\to 0}g(h)=0$ is equivalent to $\lim_{h\to 0}|g(h)|=0$. Therefore these are equivalent:

$\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}=L$

$\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)-Lh}{h}=0$

$\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{|f(x+h)-f(x)-Lh|}{|h|}=0$