# Fundamental matrix in ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $A(t)$ a matrix $n \times n$ of continuous functions in an interval $I\subseteq\mathbb{R}$. If for all $t$ $$\left[\int_{to}^tA(s)ds  \right]A(t) = A(t)\left[\int_{to}^tA(s)ds\right].$$
Show that $\displaystyle \phi(t)= e^{\large{\int _{t_0}^tA(s)ds}}$ is a fundamental matrix of $x' = A(t)x$.

Comment: Fundamental matrix is a matrix nxn whose columns form a basis of the solution space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the OP has noted, a fundamental matrix for the system $x'=Ax$ is a matrix whose columns form a basis for the solution space.

If $\phi$ itself is a solution to the system $X'=AX$, (where $X$ now takes the role not of $n$-dimensional vectors, but of $n\times n$ matrices), then each of its columns is a solution to $x'=Ax$.

One has $\displaystyle \phi'(t)=\exp\left({\int \limits_{t_0}^tA(s)\,\mathrm ds}\right)A(t)$, as a consequence of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/81184/ways-to-calculate-the-derivative-of-the-matrix-exponential) and the chain rule.

But $\displaystyle \exp\left({\int \limits_{t_0}^tA(s)\,\mathrm ds}\right)A(t)=A(t)\exp\left({\int \limits_{t_0}^tA(s)\,\mathrm ds}\right)$.

Therefore $\phi$ is a solution of $X'=AX$, which in turn implies that each of the columns of $\phi$ are solutions of $x'=A(t)x$.

It remains to prove that $\phi$ is an invertible matrix, [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/594753/55235) should be useful.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/81184/ways-to-calculate-the-derivative-of-the-matrix-exponential doesn't really apply, because they have $e^{tA}$.  What needs to be proved is that $\frac d{dt} e^{B(t)} = B'(t) e^{B(t)}$.  This definitely requires something like $B'(t) B(t) = B(t) B'(t)$, because it isn't true in general.

Comment: @StephenMontgomery-Smith Am I being too hasty in thinking that $\frac d{dt} e^{B(t)} = B'(t) e^{B(t)}$ is an immediate consequence of the chain rule? The commutativity you speak of is the given hypothesis, so it works out here.

Comment: Yes, but you have to show why the hypothesis implies it.

Comment: @StephenMontgomery-Smith That's just the fundamental theorem of calculus.

Comment: @Git Gud I'm in a first course in ODE, and I could not quite understand your statement. Please would put a few more steps in its statement. thank you

Comment: @João Before I do that, can you tell me if you understand the second paragraph?

Comment: @GitGud How is it just the fundamental theorem of calculus?

Comment: @Git Gud got it

Comment: @StephenMontgomery-Smith The integration is done entry-wise, so $\dfrac {\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}\left[\int_{to}^tA(s)ds  \right]=A(t)$. Am I missing something?

Comment: @GitGud That's correct.  But, you have to drill down into the argument at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/81184/ways-to-calculate-the-derivative-of-the-matrix-exponential and show why you use that $B(t)$ and $B'(t)$ commute to show that $\frac d{dt} e^{B(t)} = B'(t) e^{B(t)}$.  Maybe we are talking at cross purposes here.

Comment: And it is also worthwhile to find examples where $\frac d{dt} e^{B(t)} \ne B'(t) e^{B(t)}$.

Comment: @StephenMontgomery-Smith There must be something I'm missing. Why do I have to adapt the argument in the question? Why can't I just say it follows from the chain rule?

Comment: João, I added a few more steps. Note that me and @StephenMontgomery-Smith disagree about the third paragraph (he agrees it is true, but if I understood correctly he claims it is not immediate, where I claim it is).

Comment: @João Sempre às ordens.

Comment: @GitGud Let $A = \begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$ and $B = \begin{bmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$.  Then $\exp(A+tB) = \begin{bmatrix} e&(e-1)t\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$.  I calculated it by hand, and checked it using Mathematica.  Then it is easy to see that $\frac d{dt} \exp(A+tB) \ne B \exp(A+tB)$, since the left hand side is constant, and the right hand side depends upon $t$.

Comment: @StephenMontgomery-Smith Thank you for your patience. I hope you can indulge me as still don't get what the problem is. I do agree with what you showed me, but I don't understand how am I using $\frac d{dt} e^{B(t)} \ne B'(t) e^{B(t)}$ unjustifiably in my answer.

Comment: @GitGud You say that if $B'(t)$ commutes with $B(t)$, then it is obvious that $\frac d{dt} e^{B(t)} = B'(t) e^{B(t)}$.  I don't see why it is obvious, given that it isn't necessarily true if $B'(t)$ doesn't commute with $B(t)$.

Comment: @StephenMontgomery-Smith The only commutativity I see myself using is $\exp\left({\int \limits_{t_0}^tA(s)\,\mathrm ds}\right)A(t)=A(t)\exp\left({\int \limits_{t_0}^tA(s)\,\mathrm ds}\right)$ and this holds as   one of the hypothesis of the problem. So I'm guessing I'm commuting some other matrices implicitly without realizing it. Where am I doing this?

Comment: Think of this easier example: if $B(t)$ is matrix valued, it doesn't necessarily follow that $\frac d{dt} [B(t)]^n = n B'(t) [B(t)]^{n-1}$.  It isn't even true if $n = 2$.